# pdf to text convert using php and drupal

Tags: php, drupal, github, shared-libraries, pdftotext

i am using [this code](https://github.com/saubhagya/pdf2text) for conversion pdf to text, it is working fine but it is not support swedish character,
like:

```
correect swedish word     = incorrect word    
Förnamn                   = Fšrnamn,
Försäljningsdatum         = FšrsŠljningsdatum,
varumärket                = varumŠrket,
terförsäljaruppgifter     = terfšrsŠljaruppgifter
```

code is:

```
<?php
    require_once "pdf.pdf2text.inc";
    $filename = "customerfile.pdf";
    $pdf = new Pdf(urldecode($filename));
    print utf8_decode($pdf->getText());//with utf-8
    print $pdf->getText(); //without utf-8
?>
```

i am added utf-8 encoded/decoded but its not working. 
[using this code](http://drupal.org/project/pdf2text)

please anybody help me or suggest me to show proper text (Words) using this code.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a quick check - are you outputting this in a page or on the command line? If the former, is the correct content-type set?

Comment: terförsäljaruppgifter is not actually a Swedish word. I think you meant återförsäljaruppgifter.

Comment: Not sure if this might help a bit http://kunststube.net/encoding/ If you look at the code in pdf2text there may be a way to add a function to make it cope with other characters. https://github.com/saubhagya/pdf2text Maybe its authors might be happy to help if you contact them.

Comment: Their own notes https://www.drupal.org/node/1079780 suggest ways to handle the "Umlaut" for German - perhaps it might apply to Swedish. From their Drupal pdf2test issues page https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/pdf2text?status=All&categories=All

Comment: As per @GrahamAsher you could find `<html lang="sv">` under the DOCTYPE might help.

Answer (score 0):

`iconv();` might be a possibility http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-decode.php

`$myUnicodeString = "Åäö";
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $myUnicodeString);` as some comments say `UTF-8_decode();` is not enough to handle accents.

According to a comment on Drupal.org from [Saubhagya](https://www.drupal.org/user/744932):

add the octal and unicode equivalents of desired characters in array $_pdfDocToUni line 18 file initialize.pdf2text.inc (remember octal need to be in 3 digits as in other entries of array).

Then just go to line 335 of pdf2text.module and add your character in the same format of other ones.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1079780

Not sure about the use of the word "just" but it might be a help...

This appears to be the module he is talking about and it does have the array he mentioned - perhaps your version may have modules missing - there seem to be a lot of them on offer

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/pdf2text/tree/pdf2text.module?id=a15059bc1531aa336fef255397ba362c81c9fce5